# Xcopy with Python

Tags: python, xcopy

I'm trying to get xcopy working with python to copy files to a remote system. I am using a very simple test example:

```
import os

src = "C:\<Username>\Desktop\test2.txt"
dst = "C:\Users\<Username>"

print os.system("xcopy %s %s" % (src, dst))
```

But for some reason when I run this I get:

```
Invalid number of parameters
4
```

Running the xcopy directly from the command line works fine. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The Python documentation recommend using the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module instead of `os.system`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\t` is a tab character. I'd suggest using raw strings for windows paths:

```
src = r"C:\<Username>\Desktop\test2.txt"
dst = r"C:\Users\<Username>"
```

This will stop python from surprising you by interpreting some of your backslashes as escape sequences.

Comment: Or just use forward slashes; Windows is perfectly happy with them.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to using raw string literals, use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module instead of `os.system` - it will take care of quoting your arguments properly if they contain spaces. Thus:

```
import subprocess

src = r'C:\<Username>\Desktop\test2.txt'
dst = r'C:\Users\<Username>'

subprocess.call(['xcopy', src, dst])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try prefixing your strings with `r`. So `r"C:\<Username>\Desktop\test2.txt"`. The problem is that a backslash is treated as a special character within strings.